# MySQL and PHP - multiple rows or concatenated into 1 row - which is quicker?

Tags: php, mysql, string, concatenation

When storing relationship data for a user (potentially a thousand friends per user), would it be faster to create a new row for each relationship, or to concatenate all of of their friends into a string and then parse that later?

I.e.

```
Primary id  | Friend1ID  |   Friend2ID|
```

---

```
           1|         234|        5789|
           2|        5789|         234|
```

Where the IDs are references to primary IDs in a 'Users' table.

Or for the 'Users' table to just have a column called friends which may look like this:

```
Primary id  |           Friend1ID  |
```

---

```
         234|         5789.123.8474|       
        5789|                   234|
```

I'm of the understanding that string concatenation and parsing is generally quite slow, so I'd be tempted to lean towards the first method. However as the number of users grows, this then becomes a case of selecting one row and parsing it V searching millions of rows for rows which match the WHERE criteria.

Is one method distinctly faster than the other? Particularly as the number of users grows.

Comment: I believe method number 2 make more sense especially if there will be few writes/updates. I would recomment json instead of using "." to split values.

Comment: Edited as original comment has disappeared. 
Emmanuel N - presumably this would be much faster once the table grows, but would there be much in it while the table is smaller - I'm guessing not.

Comment: `would it be faster to create a new row for each relationship, or to concatenate all of of their friends into a string` _(I intentionally left out remaining clause)_ It is faster to not concatenate than to concatenate. Next Part: `and then parse that later` - _what does this mean? what are you trying to do?_ It is going to be a nightmare when you try to search for friends because you stored non-normal data in your table.  **Always start with a normalized database, then de-normalize if it improves performance on an existing application**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a second table to store the friends.

```
Users Table
----------
userid | username
1      | Bob
2      | Mike
3      | John

Users Friends Table
--------------------
userid | friend_id
1      | 2
3      | 2
```

Here you can see that Mike is friends with both Bob and John.... This is of course a very simply demonstration.

Your second option will not scale, some people may have hundreds of thousands of friends, storing each Id in a single field is going to cause a headache further down the line. adding friends, removing friends. working out complex relationships between people. Lots of over head.

Querying millions of records with a WHERE clause on a properly indexed table should take no more than a second, the first option is the better one.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer. He asks even for the slow/fast system to store the data.

Comment: @Goikiu He asked "Is there a more "correct" way of doing it?"... To which I answered. The first question is null and void by providing an answer to the second question.

Comment: I think you need however to think about slow/fast, +1 for the db model, but you haven't solved the huge load of people using the app with so a lot of query together.

Comment: I've rephrased the question to make it clearer that it's regarding the speed.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, it's confirmed my initial thoughts.

Comment: @superphonic can I just ask one thing based on your example. As you said, I can see that Mike is friends with both Bob and John. However if I was doing a select statement using Mike's userid I would need to search the friend_id column to find this out, not the userid column. Would it be more sensible to put each relationship in twice (as in my example), or would it still be reasonably quick to just search both columns in one select statement?

Comment: @TheBestBigAl You would not need to put each relationship in twice(just reversed) as again this is just over head you don't need. If you set both userid and friend_id together as a primary key, or unique (as they will never be duplicates) then your query will be extremely quick

Answer (score 2):

The "correct" way would probably be keeping multiple rows. This allows for much easier statistical analysis and more complex queries (like friends of friends) without any hacky stuff. Integer storage size is also often smaller than string storage, even though you're repeating one ID - especially if you use an appropriately sized integer store (like mediumint).

It's also more maintainable, scalable (if they start getting a damn lot of friends) export and importable. The speed gain from concatenation, if any, wouldn't be worth the rest of the benefits.

If you wanted for instance to search if Bob was a friend of Jane, this would be a single row lookup in the multiple row implementation, or in the single row implementation: get Bob's row, decode field, loop through field looking for Jane - found Jane. DBMS optimisation and indexing would make the multiple row implementation much faster in this case - if you had the primary key as (id, friendid) then it'd be pretty much instantaneous as the table would probably be hashed on that key.

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of thing I was looking to find out. If one way was distinctly faster then that would be great, but if there's not much in it then this you make a good point about scalability.

Comment: Read the extra stuff I added. Some tasks would be substantially faster with multiple rows

Comment: OK that's great. As I mentioned in my original post, I've always been under the impression that dealing with strings is generally quite slow, and I suspected that databases were probably optimised enough to overcome any problems that lots of rows may create.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the proper way to do it which might be more faster is two do a two columns table

```
      user | friend
      1    |   2
      1    |   3
```

It will simple and will make queering and updating much easier and you can have as many relationship as you want.

Don't over complicate the problem...

Answer (score -1):

... Asking for the more "correct" way is wrong itself.
It depends based on case.

If you have low access rate to your web application having more rows won't change anything on the other side of the coins (i'm not English), on large and medium application access it's maybe better to have the minimal access to the db possible.

To obtain this as you've already thinked you can concatenate the values and then split them on login of the user and then put everything into the `$_SESSION` supervar.

At least this is what i think.